# Logging mysql changes of a column/columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `products_table`
it has

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| count | product_id | vendor_id | product_name | size | sku | price |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | pro001     | ven001    | case         | 10   | A5  | 20    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2     | pro001     | ven005    | case         | 9    | A5  | 18    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3     | pro005     | ven004    | bar          | 5    | B5  | 30    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4     | pro006     | ven001    | par          | 2    | P5  | 6     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to capture and save all the values in the price column

if (any vendor) lets say ven001 comes back and changes the price to 15 tomorrow or in a month to 25 and so on, ( lets assume ven005 also updates his price ) I would like to have the previous price value to be saved as history or log relating to that product and the vendor so i will have records of all the previous price changes made by them.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | pro001     | ven001    | case         | 10   | A5  | 15   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | pro001     | ven001    | case         | 10   | A5  | 25    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | pro001     | ven001    | case         | 10   | A5  | 16    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I store this information. Should I create another table and store the previous values before inserting the new one through php or SQL Server Audit Trigger is the way to go ?? I want to use these Logs to generate timeline graph of 3 years.

Any Example / suggestion would be much appreciated.
Also is this a good approach for storing product information and it might run into tens of thousands of row. Might have 100000 products and 5000 vendor suppliers selling the same thing with different prices.

Or should each product have their own respective tables along with Audit table ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's better to create different tables. If you have a lot of vendors and their products you must create **vendor** and **product** tables, also you can create a simple log table which will contain an *vendor_id*, *product_id*, *price*, *date* (date of that changes).
Current (active) price will be stored in **product** table and logs will be stored in another table.

Something like that will be in a good fit with you.

[DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx244.png)